# compare row equality by linking values between columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df:

```
rdata = {'id': {0: 'a01', 1: 'a02', 2: 'a03', 3: 'a04', 4: 'a05', 5: 'a06', 6: 'a07', 7: 'a08', 8: 'a09', 9: 'a10', 10: 'a11'}, 'col1': {0: 123456, 1: 1234567, 2: 123456, 3: 123456, 4: 1234, 5: 123456, 6: 123456, 7: 1234, 8: 1234, 9: 12345, 10: 12345}, 'col2': {0: 'a', 1: 'c', 2: 'a', 3: 'a', 4: 'a', 5: 'a', 6: 'a', 7: 'a', 8: 'a', 9: 'b', 10: 'b'}, 'col3': {0: 'AAA', 1: 'BBB', 2: 'CCC', 3: 'DDD', 4: 'EEE', 5: 'EEE', 6: 'EEE', 7: 'EEE', 8: 'EEE', 9: 'GGG', 10: 'GGG'}, 'col4': {0: 555555, 1: 111111, 2: 222222, 3: 222222, 4: 666666, 5: 111111, 6: 111111, 7: 111111, 8: 111111, 9: 444444, 10: 333333}}
df = pd.DataFrame(rdata)
```

visually (makes more sense):

[image]

It consists of 11 samples and 4 categorical columns. I need to determine if samples are the same or not based on if the columns contain the same values.

Starting from column 4, there are 6 groups. id's a02, a06, a07, a08, and a09 are in the same group, `111111`.

We see that 111111 is linked to BBB and EEE in column 3. EEE is linked to 666666 as well, so now a05 is included in the main group.

BBB from column 3 is linked to c in column2, and EEE is linked to a in column2. now all a's and all c's from column two are now in the main group.

a and c from column2 is linked to 123456, 1234567, 1234 from column a. Now samples a01-a09 are in the same group.

samples a10 and a11 are a different group.

I am lost trying to set this up in python, and would like to return a list of what samples are in each group.

```
def same_samples(df):
    stuff happens
    grps=[[a01,a02,a03...a09],[a10,a11],[]]
    return(grps)
```

Are there any suggestions on what needs to go in the `stuff happens` section. Note that there may be 1 group, up to n groups.

expected output of above

```
same_samples(df)
[ [a01,a02,a03...a09], 
  [a10,a11] 
]
```

Comment: What is your expected output to the sample you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're tempted to use [networkx](/questions/tagged/networkx):

```
import networkx as nx

grps = [
    [n for n in df["id"] if n in cc]
    for cc in nx.connected_components(
        nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.melt("id"), "id", "value")
    )
]
```

Output :

```
[
    ["a01", "a02", "a03", "a04", "a05", "a06", "a07", "a08", "a09"],
    ["a10", "a11"],
]
```